# Losing bound events after adding Drawing Manager

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm running into an issue when I add the `DrawingManager` functionality to Google Maps. When I call `drawingManager.setMap(map)` below, I lose the click event that I add at the bottom of the `createMap` function. When I comment out `drawingManager.setMap(map)`, my click event works fine. I can't find any mention in the docs that would explain this behavior but I must be missing a step or doing something wrong.

Here is a basic version of the code that I'm using:

```
function createMap() {
  window.center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  window.drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({                 
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,                        
    drawingControl: true,                                                       
    drawingControlOptions: {                                                    
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,                         
      drawingModes: [                                                           
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON                                 
      ]                                                                         
    },                                                                          
    circleOptions: {                                                            
      fillColor: '#ffff00',                                                     
      fillOpacity: 1,                                                           
      strokeWeight: 5,                                                          
      clickable: true,                                                         
      editable: true,                                                           
      zIndex: 1                                                                 
    }                                                                           
  });                                                                           

  window.drawingManager.setMap(window.map);                                                   

  google.maps.event.addListener(window.map, 'click', function(event){
    console.log('clicked!');
  });

}
```

Here it is the broken version that runs `drawingManager.setMap(map)`:

http://jsfiddle.net/spencercarnage/4hD2S/3/

And without `drawingManager.setMap(map)`, which properly console logs 'click's from the listener:

http://jsfiddle.net/spencercarnage/4hD2S/4/

Answer (score 0):

Look like the Drawing Manager is consuming the click events.  If you disable it when you are not using it, the click event works again.  That *might* be expected, I don't know where it is documented.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Replace:

```
drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
```

with:

```
drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
```

Rookie mistake.